# FFmpeg on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I have downloaded ffmpeg libraries for iPhone and compiled them. My objective is to create a movie file from a series of images using ffmpeg libraries.The amount of documentation for ffmpeg on iphone is very less. I checked an app called iFrameExtractor, which does the opposite of what i want, it extracts frames from a video.

On the command line there is a command called

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mov
```

This turns a series of images into a video. I actually checked it on my mac and it works fine. What i wanted to know was how do we get the equivalent in iPhone. Or rather which class/api or method to call. There are a couple of examples of apps doing this on iPhone. Not sure whether they do it through ffmpeg though. Anyways, for reference "Time lapser" and "reel moments"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the source... the command line parsing should be quite straightforward to understand.

Comment: HI andrew...Thx for that info...But the number of files are gigantic. Its almost like finding a needle in a haystack..ANyways i will try that approach. Thx again

Answer (score 2):

Do you need sound ?
If you do not need sound, you can try to use openCv.
I think it is easier to use. You just call a method to append a picture to the movie:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: Hello olipion, thanks for this info...I will check it out. Does this work for iPhone though? And i dont need sound, just the video will do

Comment: I think so. I did not used opencv to do that, but I used opencv to do face detection on iphone. I think it should work.

Comment: I downloaded openCv static libraries for arm(iPhones native instruction architecture) and the libraries were generated just fine. There were no problems linking to them libraries.

As a first step, i was trying to create a .avi file using one image, to see if it works. But 
cvCreateVideoWriter always returns me a NULL value. I did some searchin and i believe its due to the codec not being present. I am trying this on the iPhone simulator.  this is what i do...

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
 IplImage *img_color = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:anImage];
        //The image gets created just fine
 
 CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("out.avi",CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'),        25,cvSize(320,480),1);
        //writer is always null

 int result = cvWriteFrame(writer, img_color);
 NSLog(@"\n%d",result);
        //hence this is also 0 all the time
 cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);

}

Comment: I am not sure about the the second parameter. What sort of codec or what exactly it does...
I am a n00B in this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe iPhone apps can call external executables (which makes sense, that would be multitasking).  You'll have to use libav* to accomplish what you're after.  Compile ffmpeg for the iPhone:
http://github.com/gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build
then read the API docs at ffmpeg.org.  For each library there should be an example file in the ffmpeg source that displays usage of that libraries core functions. i.e. in libavcodec, there is a file called api-example.c and in libavformat, there's one called output-example.c.

Comment: Hi jtrim, thanks for this info. Will check harder in the docs.